# how to get a button name as a value in python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

using tkinter i created buttons from a list and what I want to have is when I click on the button to have a lable that say HDD (the button name ) is added

for examble if I clicked on the button /dev/sda

I should have HDD /dev/sda is added

but the problem is that I always get the last list value in my list

if I click on the button that have this name /dev/sda I get HDD /dev/sdb is

added

thanx in advanced

```
HDD=[/dev/sda,/dev/sdb,/dev/sdc]
top = tkinter.Tk()
top.geometry("500x500")

def hdd():
    hdd = tkinter.Tk()
    hdd.geometry("500x500")
    len(HDD)

    for i in range(0 , len(HDD)):
        i = HDD[i]

        def addtolist():
            hlist =[]
            hlist.append(i)

            lable = Label(hdd, text="HDD {} is added to the 
            zpool".format(i))
            lable.pack()

        print(i)
        bb = Button(hdd, text=str(i), command=addtolist)
        bb.grid(row=1, column=1)
        bb.pack()


e = Button(top, text = "HDD", command = hdd)
e.grid(row=0, column=5)
```

Comment: This program does not run properly. I get the error: `NameError: name 'HDD' is not defined`. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including relevant imports and test data if needed.

Comment: Going of the title of your question only the simple way to get the value of a button name is to use `value = button_var_name['text']`.

Comment: `but the problem is that I always get the last list value in my list` Well yeah, by the time you click any button the loop has finished so `i == HDD[-1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with "i created buttons from a list"

```
from tkinter import *
top = Tk()
top.geometry("500x500")

button_names = ["dev/sda", "dev/sdb"]
button_list = [] # for later needs

#my understanding of creating buttons from a list!?
for i in button_names:
    button = Button(top, text=i, command=lambda x=i:lable_name(x))
    button.pack()
    button_list.append(button) 

#Labels are packed bellow because I don't know where you want to pack it    
def lable_name(name):
    label = Label(top, text="HDD {} is added to the zpool".format(name))
    label.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Also weird is that line *hdd = tkinter.Tk()" and then you're trying to use len() on it.

Comment: `Also weird is that line *hdd = tkinter.Tk()" and then you're trying to use len() on it` Python is case-sensitive, `hdd != HDD`

Comment: I assume he ment hdd because he never declared HDD before

Comment: I assume he didn't mean `hdd`, but forgot to include the definition of `HDD`. This code (especially `len(HDD)` and `i = HDD[i]`) only makes sense if `HDD` is a list of strings, probably the hard drive names.

Comment: We can just assume XD

Comment: am sorry for this bad explain but am new here  i already have a list that called HDD and it contain the hard drive names